# Dois Menus Horizontais Diferentes

Tags: css, xhtml

Estou criando dois menus horizontais na mesma página com definições diferentes e por isso usei uma *class* em cada uma delas.

Não estou conseguindo que um desses menus fique com a caixa de uma cor no *houver*

O que fiz foi dar um *padding* a cada um dos itens do menu para que quando se passar o mouse ficasse daquela cor.

Dei uma cor amarela para mostrar o estado padrão e outro amarelo, mais claro, quando se passa o mouse.

Resumindo: O problema é que ao passar o rato a cor amarelo claro não ocupa todo o amarelo que está em premanencia - http://jsfiddle.net/Lyu65/

Meu código atual:

```
ul.nav{
    font-family: globerthin, Verdana, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
    }
ul li.nav{
    display: inline;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 125%;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
.nav a:link{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
     }
.nav a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav a:hover{
    background-color: #faf6eb;
    text-decoration: none; 
    }
.nav a:active{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline; 
    }

<ul class="nav">        
<li class="nav"><a href="index.html#equipamentos" title="Navegar para Eqipamentos">EQUIPAMENTOS</a></li>
<li class="nav"><a href="index.html#actividades" title="Navegar para actividades">ACTIVIDADES</a></li>
<li class="nav"><a href="index.html#duvidas" title="Navegar para dúvidas técnicas">D&Uacute;VIDAS T&Eacute;CNICAS</a></li>
<li class="nav"><a href="index.html#reparar" title="Navegar para ás reparações de equipamentos">REPARA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O DE EQUIPAMENTO</a></li>
<li class="nav"><a href="index.html#usados" title"Navegar para usados">USADOS</a></li>
<li class="nav"><a href="index.html#blogue" title="Navegar para ao blogue">BLOGUE</a></li>
```

Comment: Poste seu HTML, mas pelo que você relatou, se são dois menus **diferentes** ao definir uma mesma classe para ambos os menus ele ficarão **iguais**. Supondo que eu esteja correto, ou você trabalha com IDs únicos, um para cada menu e estiliza eles individualmente ou uma classe diferente para cada, mas ainda assim estiliza individualmente. Caso existam propriedades com estilos compartilhados, pode agrupá-las numa mesma regra.

Comment: Não Bruno. Eu criei cada class com um atributo diferente. Veja o html que eu editei a pergunta.

Comment: Ou você colocou apenas parte do código ou então realmente **não**, você usou a mesma *class* para todos os elementos (todos eles têm `class="nav"`). Pior! Você deu a mesma *class* tanto para a lista (`<ul>`) quanto para seus itens (`<li>`).

Comment: Então como devo fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri onde está o problema.

No `hover` eu coloquei `a:houver` depois a cor, na verdade eu quero aplicar a cor não ao `a` mas sim ao `li`.

Portanto deve ficar assim:

```
#navt li:hover{
    background-color: #faf6eb;
}
```

Ao invés de:

```
#navt a:hover{
    background-color: #faf6eb;
}
```

Comment: @ Bruno Augusto tinha a resolução no seu código de exemplo em comentários em cima o problema é que não foi directo ao ponto. Então não tinha visto que o problema tinha sido resolvido. Foi necessário ler mais coisas para lá chegar. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Estarei comentando nesta resposta também apenas para haver um [link de demonstração](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/3PdM5/3/) de referência. Não se esqueça de marcar uma resposta como resolvida, seja a minha (que apesar de não ter o menu *inline* contém a repsosta correta) ou a sua, se achar devido.

Comment: Apesar da sua resposta resolver o problema da pergunta e ser pioneira por isso mesmo você não conseguiu responder diretamente à minha pergunta. Tive de voltar a estudar para encontrar a resposta. Depois de saber a resposta analisei a sua resposta e então vi que você tinha lá a resposta correta no meio de tanta informação. Agradeço a sua ajuda porém tente ser mais direto nas respostas. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O problema foi melhor esclarecido apenas nos comentários então, apesar de esta resposta não estar no formato de um menu horizontal, ela ainda soluciona o problema conforme exposto [na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29161/250) do próprio autor.

Ao longo dos comentários existe [um link](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/3PdM5/3/) para a mesma solução porém considerando o formato *inline*.

---

A pedido do autor uma demonstração bem simples:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu1">
    <li><a>Item #1</a></li>
    <li><a>Item #2</a></li>
    <li><a>Item #3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="menu2">
    <li><a>Item #1</a></li>
    <li><a>Item #2</a></li>
    <li><a>Item #3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu1, #menu2 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
}

#menu1 li, #menu2 li {
    padding: 5px;
}

#menu1 li {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}

#menu1 li:hover {
    background-color: #FFFF4D;
}

#menu2 li {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

#menu2 li:hover {
    background-color: #FF4D4D;
}
```

[**Demo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/3PdM5/)

Veja o que foi feito e compare com seu código atual.

Temos dois menus, mas cada um com um ID diferente, sendo assim, aquilo que for aplicada a um deles, se a regra não estiver sendo aplicada a ambos, não será aplicada ao outro.

Quando o mouse passar pelos itens de cada um o seletor `li:hover` é disparado e o *background* muda de cor.

Comment: Bruno você não entendeu a minha dúvida. Só coloquei nesta questão um dos menus horizontais. Referi apenas que tenho 2 menus horizontais na página para vocês saberem o motivo de eu ter usado uma class. O que você fez com esse código fiz eu no meu. O problema é que o backgroud-color do a hover só preenche o conteudo de cada texto e não o padding.

Comment: Eu entendi corretamente. Acontece que pelo seu CSS você define a mudança de *background* no *hover* do `<a>`, mas o *padding* está no `<li>`. Dessa forma, a mudança só vai acontecer no background do `<a>` e não na linha inteira. Da forma como eu demonstrei a troca ocorrer quando o mouse estiver sobre a linha inteira, não importa em que parte dela. Veja [na segunda revisão do código](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/3PdM5/2/), no segundo menu, quantas regras **a mais** seriam necessárias para manter o hover acontecendo no hover do `<a>`. Está tudo comentado ;)

Comment: Mas eu quero fazer o menu "inline" e não em block. Depois cm sou iniciante fica complicado entender o que escreveu. Está tudo muito diferente do que escrevi. Agradeço a ajuda e nota-se que entende do assunto mas pedia que tentasse ensinar corretamente com uma aproximação mais ao nível que estou.

Comment: Bom, pela redação é de se imaginar de que o menu horizontal já esteja em funcionamento. Estou trabalhando com informação, se eu não tenho uma definição clara do problema, não posso te ajudar. Veja se é [isso](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/3PdM5/3/) que precisa

Comment: Faça assim, pegue no código que eu coloquei no tópico e altere esse código que fique a dar certo. Use só um menu e não dois. E use aquele código. Assim ajuda, mesmo. Uma vez mais o problema é só no "a hover" parece simples mas pelos vistos não é.

Comment: Repare que quando passa o rato o amarelo mais claro não ocupa a caixa toda. Quero que ocupe. Como se consegue isso? - http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/3PdM5/3/

Comment: [Assim](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/3PdM5/4/)? Se for basta que a troca de cor ocorra no *hover* do `<ul>` ao invés do `<li>` ou mesmo do `<a>`. Mas eu realmente espero que não seja isso porque fazer isso praticamente anula todo o propósito de um *hover*.

Comment: Desculpa a minha ultima mensagem. Tentei usar aquele site que está na minha ultima mensagem mas não consegui. Agora já consegui usar o site jsfiddle. Se fores ao link que mostro neste comentário encontras lá uma parte do menu que quero fazer no meu site. Qual é o problema? Uma vez mais, quando passas o rato pelos menus a cor muda. O problema é que essa cor não ocupa toda a caixa que está de amarelo - http://jsfiddle.net/Lyu65/

Comment: Ao que parece o caso é bem o que eu demonstrei no penúltimo comentário, com a [quarta revisão](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/3PdM5/4/)

Comment: Não sei se é ou não porque não entendi nada. Eu apresentei um código de uma forma simples. Pode conter erros mas é o código mais simples. Você apresentou um código mais resumido. Ora, como ainda estou a dar os primeiros pasos não consegui entender. Seja como for já consegui fazer o que quero - http://jsfiddle.net/Lyu65/1/ Agradeço porém a ajuda.

Comment: Editei o *disclaimer* pois agora parece que a resposta voltou a ser válida.